# An alternative to Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) defines Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function $M(a,b,z) \equiv {}_1F_1(a,b,z)$ and the  first solution to the Kummer's function:
\begin{equation}
 z{\frac {d^{2}w}{dz^{2}}}+(b-z){\frac {dw}{dz}}-aw=0,
\end{equation}
The second solution is given to be $z^{1-b}\;{}_1F_1(a+1-b,2-b,z)$, from where we can get
Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function as the (weighted) sum of these two solutions as a solution. Thus

\begin{equation}
\Psi(a,b,z) \equiv U(a,b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a+1-b)}\ {}_1F_1(a,b,z)+\frac {\Gamma (b-1)}{\Gamma (a)}z^{1-b}\ {}_1F_1(a+1-b,2-b,z).
\end{equation}

My question is, what about the weighted difference of the two solutions of the Kummer equation? Such as in:

\begin{equation}
\Psi_\bullet(a,b,z) \equiv U_\bullet(a,b,z) = \frac{\Gamma(1-b)}{\Gamma(a+1-b)}\ {}_1F_1(a,b,z)-\frac {\Gamma (b-1)}{\Gamma (a)}z^{1-b}\ {}_1F_1(a+1-b,2-b,z).
\end{equation}

Is that another solution? Does it have a name? Or do the weights change, and we get some other solution?

Thanks for your help here as I gain some understanding of the confluent hypergeometric function.

Comment: I would not use the notation $\Psi$ and $U$ for two different functions.

Comment: @Gary Excellent point, fixed!

Comment: Do you know about spaces of solutions of linear ODEs? Any solution is a linear combinations of two linearly independent solutions, and any linear combinations of two linearly independent solutions is a solution.

Comment: So I understand that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two solutions, then $af(x)+bg(x)$ are also solutions. But then, what is special about these two sets of weights? How do they come about? And does it mean that $\Psi_\bullet$ is indeed a solution? How do the two weights come about?

Comment: The choice for $U$ comes from the fact that you get a clean asymptotic behaviour at infinity: http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E6 Your dotted function is also a solution but it does not have such a clean asymptotics for large $z$. Also, $U$ has nice relations with many other functions: https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.6

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, @Gary !